# can't find ip of wifi acess point

Tags: router, dhcp, wifi, access-point, lost

I setup an wireless AP (linksys wifi router) to have no dhcp and point to the main router as the default gateway.

I also set it up to obtain a ip from the network

but when i go to my main router and look for it i don't see any ip's that it could be

If i use net stumbler i can see the mac address of the wifi portion of it but Im at a loss how to get into the web console of this router

any ideas on how to "find" this router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get the MAC of the AP (should be printed on the bottom of the unit)
2. Plug directly in to AP and run [ipscan](http://www.angryip.org/w/Download) making sure to add the MAC column under Options > Select Columns

Comment: the version of ipscan from that website comes up as a virus "http://www.microsoft.com/security/portal/Threat/Encyclopedia/Entry.aspx?name=Tool%3aWin32%2fAngryscan.A&threatid=140376

Comment: It may come up as a threat because its a scanning tool, I assure you it is safe. Which one did you try to get, the beta, or stable? They specify possible warnings with the older version...

Comment: okay the mac is 00-1c-10-8e-b5-3e but that doesnt show up in the scan. Again the catch 22 is that the scaner will only scan things that have an ip but i dont think that this device does some how. even though i can connect to it and get web pages

Comment: At this point, reset it and start over. Unless this thing is actually doing anything, diminishing returns are kicking in.

Comment: Also, with something like an AP, i would also recommend giving it a static IP, and labeling the box.

Comment: If you can get to it and get web pages, what is your "gateway" IP address? That is probably the IP address of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to reset the WiFi router and then connect to the default IP, typically, 192.168.1.1?

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell if you did this or not, but plug the "LAN" side into the rest of your wired network instead of the "WAN" side.

This is also called "bridge" mode.